# Enforcing type of key in generic function input

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have the generic function:

```
function f<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
   ...
}
```

I would like to enforce the type of `T[K]` so I could perform type specific actions. For example, using string:

```
function f<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): string {
    return obj[key].toLowerCase();
}
```

Is this at all possible without casting things to `any`?

**Edit:**
To clarify, I'm looking for the ability to disallow certain keys based on the resulting type. Using the example above, something like:

```
f({a: 123, b: 'abc'}, 'b') //No errors
f({a: 123, b: 'abc'}, 'a') //Typescript error, T['a'] is not string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To restrict property names to only those having `string` value types you can use conditional types in conjunction with mapped types:

```
type StringProperties<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];

declare function f<T>(obj: T, key: StringProperties<T>): string;

f({a: 123, b: 'abc'}, 'b') // No errors
f({a: 123, b: 'abc'}, 'a') // Error: Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20StringProperties%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20string%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20f%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20StringProperties%3CT%3E)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Af(%7B%20a%3A%20123%2C%20b%3A%20'abc'%20%7D%2C%20'b')%20%2F%2F%20No%20errors%0D%0Af(%7B%20a%3A%20123%2C%20b%3A%20'abc'%20%7D%2C%20'a')%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22a%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22b%22'.)

Comment: Popping in 2.5 years later to say thank you for saving me a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the property types by adding an indexed type, forcing all properties to be of one type:

```
interface AllStringProps {
   [key: string]: string;
}

function f<T extends AllStringProps, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): string {
    return obj[key].toLowerCase();
}
```

However this contstrains you to use an index type that accepts any string as property.

To add a little bit more safety you could change the snippet to

```
type AllStringProps<T> = {
   [key in keyof T]: string;
}

function f<T extends AllStringProps<T>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): string {
    return obj[key].toLowerCase();
}
```

Here the type `AllStringProps` enforces that all keys available in `T` must be of type string. The snippet before forced all possible properties must be of type string.

In your use case, not a big difference, but I always prefer the smallest possible constraint.

### Update to a question in the comments

Lets say, we only want to allow a subset of `T`'s keys.

We could start by defining all keys which we want to allow:

```
type AllowedKeys = { "s1" , "s2" };

type AllStringProps<AllowedKeys> = {
   [key in keyof AllowedKeys]: string;
}

function f<T extends AllStringProps<AllowedKeys>, 
           K extends keyof AllowedKeys>(obj: T, key: K): string {
    return obj[key].toLowerCase();
}
```

The snippet above would allow passing the following object:

```
let t1 = {
    s1: "Hello",
    s2: "World",
    other: 4
}
```

But not this one

```
let t1 = {
    s1: "Hello",
    s2: 6,
    other: 4
}
```

Comment: This would force T to be have an index type though. Which prevents something like `f({a: 1, b: 'foo'}, 'b')` from compiling.

Comment: Yes exactly, as you allow all keys of T, you need to enforce that all keys return string.

Comment: You could enforce only a subset of T's keys to be of type string. I'll update the answer to include an example of that

Comment: Thanks. I think my question is a bit unclear. What I would like is to not allow all keys of T, only those such that T[K] is of type string (or whatever other specific type). I'll update the question with a clarification.