# Inferring specific type of value for object key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have this:

```
type KeyForValueType<T, ValueType> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ValueType ? K : never; }[keyof T];

declare function fn1<T, ValueType>(obj: T, key: KeyForValueType<T, ValueType>): void;
```

`fn1` will work as expected, it will properly limit the key I can use based on the type of value of that key:

```
fn1<{ a: number; b: string }, string>({ a: 11, b: 'str' }, 'a'); // error as expected
fn1<{ a: number; b: string }, string>({ a: 11, b: 'str' }, 'b'); // works
fn1<{ a: number; b: string }, number>({ a: 11, b: 'str' }, 'a'); // works
fn1<{ a: number; b: string }, number>({ a: 11, b: 'str' }, 'b'); // error as expected
```

I got the above from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476941/520229

However, when actually implementing the function, I am unable to get it to recognize the type of the value:

```
// with generic ValueType
function fn2<T, ValueType>(obj: T, key: KeyForValueType<T, ValueType>): void {
  const value: ValueType = obj[key];
  console.log(value);
}

// or even fixed value type
function fn3<T>(obj: T, key: KeyForValueType<T, string>): void {
  const value: string = obj[key];
  console.log(value);
}
```

Check it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDED2AnAagQwDYFcIBVwIAefAGik1wKID4oBeKAbygG0YoBLAOygGt4SAGZR8AXQBcYjuKgQAHsAg8AJgGdK2PIUhQA-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-nl3hix5bEA).

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this even possible to do with typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Accept all Object keys that map to a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764867/typescript-accept-all-object-keys-that-map-to-a-specific-type)

Comment: @jcalz Thx, you are right. Actually my solution even had some additional problems, but the one you provided worked. Voting to close.